# Based on array elements, split into two arrays while using for-each in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

Based on array elements, split into two arrays while using for-each in XSLT 1.0.

```
<n1:request>
    <n1:metadata-criteria>
        <n1:metadata-criterion>
            <n1:name>id</n1:name>
            <n1:name-exists>true</n1:name-exists>
        </n1:metadata-criterion>
        <n1:metadata-criterion>
            <n1:name>direction</n1:name>
            <n1:value>A</n1:value>
        </n1:metadata-criterion>
        <n1:metadata-criterion>
            <n1:name>radius</n1:name>
            <n1:name-exists>true</n1:name-exists>
        </n1:metadata-criterion>
    </n1:metadata-criteria>
</n1:request>
```

Here I'm using for-each for **metadata-criterion** I need to split to two arrays conditionally.
First Array : if *value* presents, I need to create as [direction-A] name and value of that element.
Second Array : if *name-exists* presents, I need to create as [id, radius] names of that element.

We are using XSLT 1.0 only.

```
<xsl:for-each select="./ns1:metadata-criterion">
            <xsl:if test="./ns1:value">
                <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:name" />
                <xsl:text>-</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="./ns1:value" />
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text> AND </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:when>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Please post what your expected output is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the following input XML (I added a namespace declaration `n1`)

```
<n1:request xmlns:n1="http://ns1.com">
    <n1:metadata-criteria>
        <n1:metadata-criterion>
            <n1:name>id</n1:name>
            <n1:name-exists>true</n1:name-exists>
        </n1:metadata-criterion>
        <n1:metadata-criterion>
            <n1:name>direction</n1:name>
            <n1:value>A</n1:value>
        </n1:metadata-criterion>
        <n1:metadata-criterion>
            <n1:name>radius</n1:name>
            <n1:name-exists>true</n1:name-exists>
        </n1:metadata-criterion>
    </n1:metadata-criteria>
</n1:request>
```

and the following XSLT-1.0 stylesheet (with a similar namespace declaration `ns1`)

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="http://ns1.com" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="no" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
        
    <xsl:template match="/ns1:request/ns1:metadata-criteria">
        <xsl:copy>
            <array1>
                <xsl:for-each select="ns1:metadata-criterion[ns1:value]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(ns1:name,'-',ns1:value)" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text> AND </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </array1>
            <array2>
                <xsl:for-each select="ns1:metadata-criterion[ns1:name-exists]">
                    <xsl:value-of select="ns1:name" />
                    <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                        <xsl:text> AND </xsl:text>
                    </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </array2>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you'll get this output:

```
<n1:metadata-criteria xmlns:n1="http://ns1.com">
    <array1>direction-A</array1>
    <array2>id AND radius</array2>
</n1:metadata-criteria>
```

Note that the namespaces are identical, but their prefixes are different(`n1` and `ns1` for the same namespace). The predicates on the `xsl:for-each` check if the given element is present.

Comment: Thank you, with little tweaking its working in my case.